# Why is else-statement not working for isset?

Tags: php, post, if-statement, isset

I found something strange happening with this:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
else{
    echo "please enter name";
}
```

in the above example the else statement does not work.

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    echo "please enter name";
}
else{
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

but when I do it like this, it works. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: `$_POST['name']` is getting set but it contains `null` value so add  `if((isset($_POST['name'])) and (empty($_POST['name']))`

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` look like? Perhaps `$_POST['name']` _is_ set, but just falsy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are submitting a form, where the field `name` is *empty*, but it exists (or in other words *isset*).

The difference between `isset` and `empty` is, that the latter assumes that `$_POST['name']` exists, but contains an empty value, e.g. `""` or `0`, whereas the first only checks *if* `$_POST` contains an element `name`.

When your form contains a field, it will be submitted and therefore is set, whether it has any contents or not (i.e. is empty).

Comment: Thank you, I believe this answers my question :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
isset() function is not able to fetch blank && zero value.

so always use empty() with it.

if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))
{
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
else 
{
    echo "please enter name";
}
```

--
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['name']` is getting set but it contains null value so add  `if((isset($_POST['name'])) and (empty($_POST['name']))`